# How do I scale a Bootstrap 4 form to fit the width in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a form made using Bootstrap 4, which I wish to scale to fit the viewport of a mobile user.

Currently, what mobile users see is this:

[image]

As you can see, the form inputs aren't fitting the width of the screen. I wish for them to occupy the width of the screen.

I have the viewport set in the head like so:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">`

I've also tried doing:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  form-row col-xs-6 {
    width: 100% !important; 
  }
}
```

but to no avail.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: do you want this form design 50% in desktop? and full width in mobile?

Comment: Can I ask you why you're using col-xs-6 and not col-xs-12 ?

Comment: by the way your media css not correct you need to add `dot` `.form-row.col-xs-6`

Comment: if you want to add this by bootstrap class then show your code.

Comment: please put down your website link!

Answer (score 1):

use the inputs with in `container`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="usr">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```